# problem with rails  and ie sessions from  link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails application with sub domains 
upon the login
in chrome and ff everything is working ok
but in IE when after I do the authentication  processes the session is lost
the more peculiar thing is that in IE the lost session behavior is happens only when I redirected to the subdomain by link (if I type the subdimain address in the url bar the session is not lost)

somebody have some guess how I can solve it?

Comment: Consider posting whatever error (logs) you get when accessing here.  Are you sure it's a browser issue rather than subdomain issue?

Comment: I assume that if it works for me in all other browsers it is a browser issue and not subdomains.
I also edited my question so please read it again I will be very glad if you could help me now

Answer (score 0):

I think that I found the solution after many many hours without a sleep

It appears that in my session.store.rb file was the following 

APPFOLDER::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_myapp_session'
,
after reading some post about it I added the domain to this line like this:

APPFOLDER::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_myapp_session', :domain => ".mydomain.com"

and it seems to solve the problen